# Are there any php classes or libraries out there to handle oAuth 2.0?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

Before I go and write a wrapper for Facebook and oAuth 2.0 I was wondering if anyone knew of any code out there that anyone else has used already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- There is an [extension to PHP](http://php.net/oauth) that supports OAuth. It was written by [John Jawed](http://jawed.name/). An example can be found [here](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/oauth/trunk/examples/) and a [walkthrough](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/50-Using-pecloauth-to-post-to-Twitter.html) is also available.
- This [pecl package](http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth) is considered the de facto standard by Rasmus Lerdorf.
- [Andy Smith](http://term.ie) has written a [basic PHP library](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/) for OAuth.
- Cal Henderson has contributed a [simple OAuth library](https://svn.iamcal.com/public/php/lib_oauth/lib_oauth.php) that primarily handles signing.
- [HTTP_OAuth](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_OAuth) is a PEAR package [developed by Jeff Hodsdon and Bill Shupp](http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=607) (Digg). You can try it out using this [tool](http://jeffhodsdon.com/HTTP_OAuth/examples/index.php).
- There is now an [OAuth component for CakePHP](http://cakebaker.42dh.com/downloads/oauth-component-for-cakephp/).
- Justin Richer has developed [a plugin](http://community.elgg.org/pg/plugins/jricher/read/385119/oauth) for the [Elgg](http://elgg.org/) social networking platform, based on the [basic PHP library](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/). This library allows Elgg to act as both an OAuth client (to access other services) and server (allowing OAuth-protected access to the Elgg API). The library supports both version 1.0 and revision 1.0a simultaneously. Documentation can be found [on the Elgg wiki](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/OAuth).
- [Zend_OAuth](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=37957) was contributed by Pádraic Brady. The source code can be found [here](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/incubator/library/Zend/Oauth/).

Source: http://oauth.net/code/

Comment: I wonder if any of them supports 2.0. You may also try http://code.google.com/p/oauth2-php/ which supports Oauth 2.0 draft 9

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [PHP-OAuth2](https://github.com/adoy/PHP-OAuth2) library by [adoy](https://github.com/adoy) to write a sample OAuth 2.0 client.

The docs at the time of writing describe it as a Light PHP wrapper for the OAuth 2.0 protocol (based on OAuth 2.0 Authorization Protocol draft-ietf-oauth-v2-15)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PHP's OAuth extension](http://php.net/oauth) or http://code.google.com/p/oauth/.