# Instagram how to get access_token

Tags: javascript, instagram

I'm new to Instagram apps development and struggling with this issue for some time now. Basically, this is how it looks like:

I'm redirecting user to authorization url like this:

```
window.open("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" + igClientId + "&redirect_uri=" + igCallbackUrl + "&response_type=code", "_blank");
```

Then, when user will login, page reloads and Instagram CODE is added at the end of callback url ('`?code=returned_by_instagram_code`').

And this is the place where I've stuck.

How can I obtain returned code from url after page reloads (it is stored in cookies or session so I could access it in some way, or should I get it somehow through callback url and some function attached to it)?

How next, when I'll obtain the code, can I send (`POST`) request to Instagram for `access_token`?

---

Thank you in advance for any help.

*PS. I'm using javascript without any frameworks (e.g. jquery) and this is the response that I'm looking for.*

Comment: This tutorial includes a link that generates your auth token and your user id. Then it goes on to show you what you can do with it. See here: http://www.blueprintinteractive.com/blog/how-instagram-api-fancybox-simplified

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation on using Client-Side access token generation only (http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) and the key thing you need to change is the responsecode in your URL to be: &response_type=**token**

Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication
If you’re building an app that does not have a server component (a purely javascript app, for instance), you’ll notice that it’s impossible to complete step three above to receive your access_token without also having to ship your client secret. You should never ship your client secret onto devices you don’t control. Then how do you get an access_token? Well the smart folks in charge of the OAuth 2.0 spec anticipated this problem and created the Implicit Authentication Flow.

Step One: Direct your user to our authorization URL

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECTURI&response_type=token
```

At this point, we present the user with a login screen and then a confirmation screen where they approve your app’s access to their Instagram data. Note that unlike the explicit flow the response type here is “token”.

Step Two: Receive the access_token via the URL fragment

Once the user has authenticated and then authorized your application, we’ll redirect them to your redirect_uri with the access_token in the url fragment. It’ll look like so:

```
http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=270740070.f59def8.d58713f2c81741c5b3686109306f98b4
```

Simply grab the access_token off the URL fragment and you’re good to go. If the user chooses not to authorize your application, you’ll receive the same error response as in the explicit flow

Answer (score 1):

A simple example, get your token in registration app on api.instagran (https://instagram.com/developer/clients/register/). Make your login before:

```
var accessToken = '5e6e329062f047dd95ggj6c9df202c828';

$.ajax({
 url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular',
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 type: 'GET',
 data: {client_id: accessToken},
 success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    for(x in data.data){
      $('ul').append('<li><img  src="'+data.data[x].images.low_resolution.url+'"></li>');  
    }
},
error: function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The igCallbackUrl will redirect to a page. The code can be accessed as a GET parameter to that request.

Something like GET['code'] in php. If you give more details about the Server side framework then it will be helpful to answer your qwery.

You can use  github.com/Instagram/instagram-javascript-sdk if you are using on Javascript.

Comment: It's not so simple. The flow looks like this:

**open instagram authorization url -> click on button to authorize app -> instagram will redirect you to igCallbackUrl with '?code=returned_code' at the end of url**

So code can be accessed only via address bar.

But even if I will obtain the code from address bar, I'm not able to post it to instagram to get access_token.

Do you have any ideas how this can be done in javascript?

Comment: This is standard oauth protocol. The way you are stugling i would suggest you to use a stand outh library in ur prefered language.

Comment: Instagram is using oauth 2.0. Do you have maybe any suggestions regarding its implementation?

Comment: This one is still on basics. http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg08521.html (Javascript).  You can check here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551108/are-there-any-php-classes-or-libraries-out-there-to-handle-oauth-2-0 for some php library related to Auth 2.0

Comment: I was trying to use the first on (in JS) but it does not work as it should :/ Still looking for good solution to connect with JS to Instagram...

Comment: I found this https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-javascript-sdk. I think this should work for you.

Comment: I'm using it now and was able to obtain access_token :) One tip: To get this SDK flow working correctly, you need to create on your page (in HTML code) an element with id="ig-root". Otherwise it will fail.